# how to read large csvs in multiple zipfiles very quickly using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip, glob

I'm using below code to read multiple multiple CSV's in multiple Zipfiles (one CSV per Zipfile) and data is huge (each csv is 1.5GB and I have more than 30 zipped CSV's) and that's why I prefer not unzipping them. however, it gets very slow when I want to concat many of them. is there a more effecient code to make the process quicker?

```
     import os
     import glob
     import pandas as pd
     os.chdir(r"path") 
     extension = 'zip'
     all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
     combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
```

Comment: If you have enough resources, you can use Dask or Polar.

Comment: We do have servers with high capabailities at work. Never thought of utilizing them but I will consider it. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want unzip them first, if you have servers with high capabilities.  These are large files and their data has to exist somewhere. If it's not on disk, it's in memory. Is it better to have 30x1.5G in memory or on disk?

Comment: @ZachYoung I didn't say I'm saving them on my laptop, they're placed on a shared folder actually. Regarding the servers I mentioned, I need to arrange with a lot of departments before I'm allowed to test using them. Nevertheless, are you implying that reading from the unzipped files will make the loading quicker than reading them while it's zipped?